# How to make typer traceback look normal

Tags: python, command-line-interface, traceback, typer

When using [typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com/) to parse CLI arguments, I get very verbose and colorful error messages. How can I get a normal Python traceback?

See screenshot for an example traceback (just the first few lines) for illustration of the verbose style:

```py
❯ python scripts/add_priors.py             
╭─────────────────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ────────────────────────────────╮
│ /Users/corneliusromer/code/nextclade_data_workflows/sars-cov-2/scripts/add_priors.py:26 in main  │
│                                                                                                  │
│   23 │   import polars as pl                                                                     │
│   24 │                                                                                           │
│   25 │   priors = (                                                                              │
│ ❱ 26 │   │   pl.scan_ndjson(ndjson, infer_schema_length=10000)                                   │
│   27 │   │   .select(                                                                            │
│   28 │   │   │   [                                                                               │
│   29 │   │   │   │   pl.col("nearestNodes"),                                                     │
│                                                                                                  │
│ ╭─────────────────────────────────────────── locals ───────────────────────────────────────────╮ │
│ │   json = <module 'json' from                                                                 │ │
│ │
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can disable it on a one-off basis by setting the environment variable `_TYPER_STANDARD_TRACEBACK=1`.

Disabling rich exceptions is possible by passing the kwarg `pretty_exceptions_enable=False` when initializing `typer`:

```py
import typer

app = typer.Typer(pretty_exceptions_enable=False)

@app.command()
def main():
    raise Exception("test")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

See the [documentation](https://typer.tiangolo.com/tutorial/exceptions/#disable-pretty-exceptions) for more options

Answer (score 3):

Also, if you're not using sub-command. i.e. using just `typer.run(main)` then create an instance of typer regardless and run the `main` command explicitly.
e.g.

```py
app = typer.Typer(pretty_exceptions_enable=False)
app.command()(main)
app()
```

Note: I was going to leave it as comment below accepted answer but I can't add multiple lines in comment and python is picky about spaces/newlines.