# How to change Traceback back to normal?

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

My most recent env prints traceback like this

```
╭───────────────────── Traceback (most recent call last) ──────────────────────╮
```

which is beyond useless.

I've already looked at this [How to make typer traceback look normal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76375307/how-to-make-typer-traceback-look-normal) but it doesn't help.

My hunch is it may be about Huggingface but maybe something else like `datasets` or `evaluate` but I can't find anything useful so far.

How to make stacktrace print everything it need to again?

Comment: What does "it doesn't help" mean ? No result ? What is your code ?

Comment: Are you running in an IDE?  Does this happen at a command line?

Comment: @TimRoberts Specifically I run it in slurm. But this also happen in command line.

Comment: Have you tried `set _TYPER_STANDARD_TRACEBACK=1`?

Comment: @TimRoberts yes both `_TYPER_STANDARD_TRACEBACK=1` and `TYPER_STANDARD_TRACEBACK=1`. nothing changed

Comment: I kinda suspect it has nothing to do with typer and more about huggingface or some other libs that are needed to train it

Comment: The fancy header you're showing is clearly coming from `typer`.

Comment: Did you meant that the traceback only prints the header and nothing else?

Comment: @danieltan95 No, it prints only 80 characters per line with fancy but useless `typer` style formatting.

Comment: @NatthaphonHongcharoen seems like what huggingface is using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is [this thing](https://github.com/Textualize/rich) that causes the issue. So `pip uninstall rich` solved everything.

## Edit July 3rd, 2023

This seems to be the issue with `accelerate` as I originally anticipated. In this case it default to use `rich` when available. So `ACCELERATE_DISABLE_RICH=1` should fix the [issue](https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate/issues/1630) in case other libs require `rich` for something else.